# How to enable ECN marking in IP header in Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

Is the ECN marking in the IP header is performed by default in Ubuntu (4.15.x kernel) or should the kernel be recompiled with a special option? I configured a RED ingress queue at an Ubuntu machine, `net.ipv4.tcp_ecn` is set to `1` in all hosts of the network and ECN is enabled in the `tc qdisc` command. I see dropped packets due to congestion but there are no marked packets.

Comment: Is the machine a router, or just an end node? _Where_ in the network does the congestion occur?

Comment: I am using 4 ubuntu machines using this topology: client --- rt1 --- rt2 --- server.
```iperf -s``` is running at the server side and ```iperf -c server -P 100 -d``` at the client side.
(client --- rt1): 100mbit 1 ms latency;
(rt1 --- rt2): 10mbit 1ms latency;
(rt2 --- server): 100mbit 1ms latency;

The RED queue is configured at the client-facing interface of rt1 using ```tc qdisc add dev ens36 root red limit 50000 min 4167 max 12500 burst 7 avpkt 1000 probability 0.5 bandwidth 100mbit ecn```